# Visual Studio 2010 or MonoDevelop

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm very new to Mono for Android and am having issues getting started - specifically as a new user I tend to have to step through code to ensure that it is doing what I want.  This is extremely slow using VS 2010 and the latest version of Mono for Android.  Just wondering if MonoDevelop will improve matters and whether it is as easy to develop using MonoDevelop rather than VS 2010 which is my normal tool.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know the slowness is not due to Visual Studio but to the Android Emulator itself.

Debugging Monodroid on a physical device is lots faster with either VS or MonoDevelop, but then you need to buy a license to be able to deploy to anything else than the emulator..

I would keep using Visual Studio as it's far more complete and stable than MonoDevelop.
if performances are really an issue you might need to consider purchasing a license for Monodroid and use a physical Android device.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience Mono Develop is more lightweight, but also more buggy.  For the moment I am using Visual Studio.  It compiles resources right away whereas Mono Develop sometimes does not recognize when I've added a resource.  But you are right about the debugger.  It is painfully slow.  Other than the debugger I have found developing in MonoDroid to be fairly productive.

Comment: Thanks both - I'll purchase a license as it does apparently work better on a physical device.  Is it just me or is it quite difficult to get started with Mono for Android?  Maybe I need a sample application as I am finding simple tasks are taking me ages because I just can't find examples and/or documentation.  Expect I'll be posting here a lot!

Comment: Just keep in mind that you don't have to look for just monodroid examples, most java examples can be used with minimal conversion effort and "android" provides a richer set of search results than "monodroid". Just run whenever you see [Parcelable](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/about/limitations) used.  Also make sure you download the example code [xamarin provides](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples) and also check out [Greg Shackles blog](http://www.gregshackles.com/), he has some nice source code up on [Github](https://github.com/gshackles/Sample-Projects/tree/master/MonoDroid/)